# Error on creating new action type

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

I'm getting the following error when trying to create new action type:

> You have been temporarily blocked from performing this action.
>
> If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.

I suppose, that I'm seeing this message by mistake (btw, "let us know" - is the link, which redirects you to 404)

Who should I contact to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should receive email from Facebook.

Comment: Year, I should, but I didn't. How to resolve that issue? I definitely need to create a new action